# MPChart Android - Line chart has little cut at top side

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart, mpchartios

I am using MP Chart in Android. Reference : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Displaying Line Chart properly.

But then added below properties in it :

```
lineChart.axisLeft.setLabelCount(10)
lineChart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
lineChart.axisLeft.axisMaximum = 100f
```

But there is some cut at the top of the chart as below :

[image]

XML tag is as below :

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
         android:id="@+id/chartChargeOverTime"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/_250sdp" />
```

What might be the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some padding in your `LineChart`'s parent.

Comment: Its not working..I have resolved it by setting lineChart.axisLeft.axisMaximum to 101f or 102f but want solutions if there any other.

Comment: Try giving some padding to Linechart's parent.

Comment: Its already there. I have also displayed a text view above this graph. there might some other issue.

Comment: TextView also doesn't appear?

Comment: no no I have cropped this image. TextView appers there.. let me edit image in question.

Comment: Edited image in question.

Comment: In my layout I can see space between textview and chart means they are not overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0):

Normally graph take few more space to draw its curve and it crosses the max limit of axis we provide. so always try to give more space to your graph than you actually need.

> Change

lineChart.axisLeft.axisMaximum = 100f

> to

lineChart.axisLeft.axisMaximum = 110f

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: @LucaKiebel added sir :)